# Using glUniform and binding an UBO at the same time

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

As far as I understand uniforms in user defined uniform blocks are still regular uniforms. What happens if I use glUniform* to access it directly and at the same time bind a UBO to its binding point? Is this defined behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's impossible. While uniforms in a uniform block are "uniforms" in some sense, that doesn't mean that block uniforms are the same as non-block uniforms in all ways.

Uniforms in a block do not have a location. If you try to use `glGetUniformLocation` with that uniform's name, it will return -1 (unless there's some non-block uniform with that name). Therefore, there is no way to use `glUniform*` to set their value.